# Force websites to display in Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I used below "crude" code to display a set of websites via an iframe. When one clicks **Next** button the next website in the embedded website list, shows up in an iframe. I also have **Jump**, **Reload** etc.

But my problem is that, few websites display outside the iframe and replace the current window, while one site displays well in iframe but sends a page outside the iframe when a link on it is clicked.

I want to force every site and the links on them to display in the iframe. Except popups. Thanks for any help.

```
<script>
var s=[
"gin.htm",
"http://samplewebsite1.com",
"http://samplewebsite2.com",
"http://samplewebsite3.com",
];
var adr,i,x=0,c=s.length;
function address() {
adr=prompt('Enter your bitcoin address:');
s=s.map(function(x){
return x.indexOf("a=") != -1 ? x + adr : x; 
});
}
function next(){
x+=1;
if (x>c-1)
  {
  x=0;
  }
changeSrc();
}
function prev(){
x-=1;
if (x<=0)
  {
  x=c-1;
  }
changeSrc();
}
function jumpTo() {
i=prompt("Enter a number to skip to that faucet.");
x=0;
while (i!=x) {
  if (x>c-2) {
  break;
  }
 x+=1;
}
changeSrc();
}
function newTab() {
var win=window.open(document.getElementById("fm").src, '_blank');
win.focus();
}
function changeSrc() {
document.getElementById("fm").src=s[x];
}
</script>
```

This is the Iframe;

```
<iframe name="iFrame" id="fm" left="0" top="56" width="100%" style="height:    99vh;" frameborder="0" position="absolute" src="./gin.htm">
```

Comment: I haven't looked at your implementation but keep in mind this is next to impossible to do properly - plenty of sites will actively avoid embedding. Search around for 'frame busting'.

Comment: This the website I implemented it: 
[link](http://btcoin.ga)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was thinking what **pvg** was getting at... If the sites that you are embedding in an `<iframe>` element are not under your management (and therefore you cannot control their behavior when refusing embedding, or if they contain links with external/unique target windows), what is the significance/purpose of having them on your website, contained within an `<iframe>`?  Why not give them a `target="_blank"` link and let the wind blow leaves where they may go?

Comment: The websites are bitcoin faucets that have my referral code appended in them. So having a rotator site helps users navigate to all the sites from one window.

Comment: @Sunny You're better off getting in touch with these sites and working out some sort of embeddable components you can use - that's what sites that _want_ embedding typically do. Framing is so widely abused for anything from misrepresenting the origin of content to outright fraud that not only might you annoy the embedded sites, your own site ends up automatically looking less trustworthy.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [sandbox attribute for iframes](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_sandbox.asp)

```
<iframe sandbox="">
```

Comment: Sandbox will block form submission and script execution. The websites (bitcoin faucets) have those.

Comment: @Sunny In that case put sandbox="allow-forms". As far as script execution is concerned, ask them to download the same scripts in their own frame and then start the execution.

Answer (score 0):

To to avoid complication and stress, I will just do as @zapotecH advised, drop the website links on a page with `target="_blank"` link.

Thanks everyone for your time.